# How can new Nuget packages in an upstream view be pushed to my feed automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, manage-nuget-packages

I’m using Azure DevOps and have created a Nuget feed within the portal UI. I’ve set a single upstream source that’s an Azure Artifacts feed. The location is a Nuget feed *view*.

Right now, when a Nuget package is published to the upstream view’s feed, I need to manually install the package once for it to appear in my feed.

Is there a way for new or updated packages in the upstream view to automatically be pushed to my feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for new or updated packages in the upstream view to automatically be pushed to my feed?

I am afraid there is no such way to add a new or updated packages in the upstream view to automatically be pushed to your feed. And I suppose this is unnecessary.

That because Azure Artifacts feed will **cache** these packages automatically when we download any packages from the Upstream sources, so that we could see it next time and no need to download it from the Upstream sources again.

So it is used to cache those packages we have used, if we cache any new or updated packages (We may not use them at all in the current project.) in the upstream view to the feed automatically, those unused packages will make our feeds heavy and inefficient. Fast and efficient is the reason why we cache these packages in our feed.

Of course, if the above is not the point you care about, you are more concerned that you can see any new or updated packages in your feed at your first sight, you can consider to push those packages to your feed directly.

Hope this helps.